# Does git track resource forks?

Tags: git, macos, version-control, metadata

I ask myself this every time I replace a Photoshop `.psd` file that I have under version control.

You can see with `ls -l` that PS has created a thumbnail icon in the resource fork.

Comment: updated my answer after your comment, removing obsolete information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git will not track metadata, as those resources are not part of the *content* of the file (so **your answer is "no"**).

In his "Cross-Platform Version Control" entry, [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narbski) comments:

> The issue of extra metadata that is not SCM-sane, and which different filesystems can or cannot store.
> Examples include full Unix permissions, Unix ownership (and groups file belongs to), other permission-related metadata such as ACL, extra resources tied to file such as EA (extended attributes) for some Linux filesystems or (in)famous resource form in MacOS (resource fork on MacOS vs. xattrs on Linux: issue 5 in [Eric Sink article](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/quirky.html)).

> This is not an issue for SCM: *source* code management system to solve.
> Preserving extra metadata indiscrimitedly can cause problems, like e.g. full permissions and ownership.
> Therefore SCM preserve only limited SCM-sane subset of metadata.
> If you need to preserve extra metadata, you can use (in good SCMs) hooks for that, like e.g. [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/%7Ejoey/code/etckeeper/) uses [metastore](http://david.hardeman.nu/software.php) (in Git).

---

[Thomas Tempelmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43615/thomas-tempelmann) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130059/does-git-track-resource-forks/1130841#comment125073972_1130841):

> Actually, since macOS 10.12, `textClippings` store the info also in the data fork, in `plist` format, with the same keys and values of the resource fork's contents.
>
> The only thing that won't work is QuickLook if the rsrc is missing, but opening these files will show the content.
> Therefore, storing `.textClipping` files in Git is not hopeless.

Comment: That 2nd bullet point is about 15years out of date, these days PS only puts pointless stuff you don't want in the RF. Your "no" is correct, but the previous part seems to contradict that.

Comment: "Adobe Photoshop 3.0.4 Software Development Kit, Copyright 1991- **1995** , Adobe Systems": @Rhythmic Fistman: good point. I will remove the first part (now obsolete) of my answer.

Comment: Technically, a resource fork is file data, as a second (parallel) stream. Resource forks are not necessarily metadata, either. For instance, ".textClipping" files are solely storing their information in the resource fork, while the data fork remains empty, and the content is certainly not metadata.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Good points (12 years later), thank you. Maybe this is why there was a PR proposed to ignore .textClipping in `macOS.gitignore` (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/3550)

Comment: @VonC Actually, since macOS 10.12, textClippings store the info _also_ in the data fork, in plist format, with the same keys and values of the resource fork's contents. The only thing that won't work is QuickLook if the rsrc is missing, but opening these files will show the content. Therefore, storing .textClipping files in git is not hopeless.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **no**.

On the mac, by default, git does not track resource forks, or xattrs or finder info.

`git` will "slice" your resource forks right off, which is exactly what I wanted.

Other tools, like `cp` and `rsync` have been patched on the mac to preserve
this metadata, which at times is convenient and at other times annoying.

`git` is not yet annoying. Or convenient, depending on your POV.